# Saving an Excel File that has not changed will change the binary

Tags: excel, version-control

Whenever I save an Excel file, the saved binary will be different compared to when I opened it. This is even true if I did not change anything. This is because Excel saves non content related actions like selections for e.g.

When dealing with a version controlled file I do not want the binary to change if content has not changed. In that case I do not even want to save changes to a column width for e.g.

I want to see as few changes as possible in binary files. To get rid of many of them I already export and remove all VBA modules from the Excel file before committing. The VBA modules are then versioned as text files.

A simple command line tool that tells me if two excel files are content-wise the same or not would be good enough. It should not be to difficult to write such a tool using [this library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42504/ExcelFormat-Library) but that would only supports Excel97 xls files. Libraries using OLE are more flexible but far to slow and unstable.

**Best for me would be VBA code or other means that suppresses file-saving when no *real* change had happened.**

Any hints?

Comment: Maybe save as xml and parse-compare the xml that relates to data and formulas? But you would have to handle things like defined names as well.

Comment: @Charles, is the distinction between content and other stuff in the xml representation easy? Then it would be a possible way to go. I hope there is something more convenient though.

Comment: Depends what you mean by content. I would suggest you look at the XML and judge for yourself.